# ActiveRecord find all children of child resources

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have `Project has_many :locations` and `Locations has_many :comments`, and `Project has_many :plans` and `Plan has_many :comments`. How do I select all the comments of all the commentable resources that belong to a project? I'm using `ActiveAdmin` and `ActiveAdmin::Comment` if that's relevant. What I've tried:

```
p = Project.first
comments = p.locations.map(&:comments).flatten + p.plans.map(&:comments).flatten
```

But is there an ActiveRecord or Rails way to do this? Or is there a SQL join that could do all that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you make has_many location_comments through locations and the same for plans will be better. Also you can make model method like:

```
def all_comment
   self.location_comments + self. plans_comments
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's exactly what I did. I have a Project#all_comments looks almost like yours. But that's not the problem. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient ways to query these comments.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your answer close enough. I tried again using `has_many location_comments, through: locations, source: :comments`. This is indeed much better. I am now able to find all comments through two join queries. I'm wondering still though, if there is a better way to find it using one query. :) Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll accept it if no better solution shows up before tomorrow.